# C# .NET: how to pause and resume a program execution on a keypress?

Tags: c#, .net

it's a .NET non GUI application. It is specified as a console application, but the console is not really used. what the application does is  GUI testing of other applications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Others have described how you'd start/stop the problem execution ... for the actual key trapping, I'd suggest [registering a global hotkey](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/180436-global-hotkeys/) - but, you'd need to have a Windows form handle available to you, so I'd also suggest either launching your command-line utility from a GUI app, or simply including the functionality in a GUI app.

Is this kind of change possible?

EDIT: Christian Liensberger has made what looks like an [excellent wrapper for this](http://www.liensberger.it/web/blog/?p=207) on his blog.

Comment: A global hotkey doesn't need a window handle. It just needs to handle messages on that thread.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to have your main thread waiting on `Console.Read()` (or `Console.ReadKey()`) all the time and do the actual work on another thread. When the main thread detects a keypress it needs to somehow notify the other thread to pause or resume (eg. using a `WaitHandle`).

If the worker thread is doing something really simple and it's safe to suspend it at any time then you may be able to just suspend/resume the thread itself rather than doing any notifications.

Comment: but this would only work if the console has focus, am I right? but in my application this is difficult since the tested GUI usually has the focus (actually almost all of the time)

Comment: Yes, you're right - if doesn't have focus then you'd have to register a global hotkey, as overslacked says.

Answer (score 1):

Ok It Should look like this..

```
//Assuming the thread name given is 'newthread'   
//First Start a thread     

newthread.Start();   

//use Console Key Class to read a key from keyboard    
ConsoleKeyInfo cki = new ConsoleKeyInfo();  
cki = Console.ReadKey(true);

//I am using letter 'p' to pause    
if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.P)   
{  
  newthread.Suspend();  
  Console.WriteLine("Process Is Paused,Press 'Enter' to Continue...");  
}  

//Thread Resumption can only occur through another thread   
//If the thread control has passed on to the main function    
//resume it from there    


// Resuming Thread if paused   
if (newthread.ThreadState>0)    
{    
  ConsoleKeyInfo ckm = new ConsoleKeyInfo();   
  ckm = Console.ReadKey(true);    
  if (ckm.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)    
   {    
     Console.WriteLine("Resuming Process...");    
     newthread.Resume();    
   }       
}
```

Note:This should work fine for now, but in reality you should synchronise your threads. When you will run the program then it will say that the pause and resume functions are obsolete. It will tell you to synchronise the threads.